# scripting language with easy UI development capabilities

Tags: scripting-language

I have to develop a simple application for Windows that manages a hashmap.  Users will enter a keyword in a text area and get some data back, that's all it has to do.

The backend part of this is dead simple but I'm unsure of how to produce the UI.

I would like to get some recommendations for scripting languages that include UI creation capabilities.  In the past (more than 15 years ago) I used TCL/TK to do this sort of thing but I'm hoping there is something much simpler that matches the simplicity of my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tcl/Tk](http://www.tcl.tk) is still one of the simplest ways to do stuff like this (and has progressed quite far in the past 15 years if you find you need more power later).

Answer (score 1):

Download [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) and create a WinForms application. Visual Studio has a Design view that allows you to create UIs with a few mouse drags and clicks; it really is dead simple. And there are many tutorials and examples.

Answer (score 0):

U can use python Tkinter library , it is easy , for windows you can use Qt for interface design, it is also handy.